# CSS in WebKit: Overriding '-webkit-border-image' with 'none' or equivalent

Tags: css, webkit

I have a CSS style which sets up a particular '-webkit-border-image' property for an 'a' tag (to allow a scaling image to be used as a surrounding frame).

My question is how to establish a separate style rule which will override this so that no border image will be applied. I've tried the following:

```
-webkit-border-image: none !important;
```

That doesn't seem to do anything - at least in Chrome Mac 15.0.874.83 beta.

I can't simply disable the border, or set the border width to zero, since this particular style needs a border (which is set up using a separate rule).

Any hints would be appreciated.

Notes:
The -webkit-border-image forms an outer border around an 'a' element. I need to remove JUST the -webkit-border-image, not the whole border. The 'a' element also has a style rule of:

> border: 4px solid rgba(13,13,13,0.88);

and I need to retain this, so I can't just do:

> border: none

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/grw1/jtuUD/). Note that I also can't remove the offending class from the element - the markup is fixed.

Thanks.

Comment: By button background do you mean an input tag? Can you post a test case HTML we all can access so we can get a better view? Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, thanks - I've added more notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into [its W3school entry](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp) to see what the default value is, it looks like its:

```
-webkit-border-image: none 100% 1 0 stretch;
```

i tried your jsfiddle link and i dont see any border images when i view as is on mac safari 5.1 and mac chrome 14.0

Comment: Thanks, but as explained in the question, I can't do that. I need to have a border, which is defined as a separate rule.

Comment: I have updated the JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/grw1/jtuUD/1/

Using your suggestion seems to work there, so I suspect I have an inheritance issue.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Mind you it was also working when I just had -webkit-border-image set to none. I'm a bit iffy about the version of your Mac Chrome though. It's really 5.0.8 as you said? Seems very far to the 14.0.835.202 I have. You probably haven't updated in a while have you?

Comment: Ah, no! I copied and pasted the version wrong - I'm running 15.0.874.83 beta! I missed the leading '1'.

Thanks for your help.